# nodeJS require.paths resolve problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, relative-path, require, commonjs

I am trying to require a file relatively and mysteriously the following is happening

This works well which points to `/Users/marcos/Desktop/Taper/lib/utils.js`

```
myPath = "/Users/marcos/Desktop/Taper/lib/./utils";
require(myPath);
```

This doesn't but it should point to exactly the same file:

```
require.paths.unshift("/Users/marcos/Desktop/Taper/lib")
require("./utils"); //Doesn't work with './'
require("utils"); //Works Fine
```

Anyone knows why I can't still use `./` in this case for loading the path since

```
require("path").resolve("/Users/marcos/Desktop/Taper/lib", "./utils")
```

results in:

```
"/Users/marcos/Desktop/Taper/lib/utils"
```

anyway?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that the docs say [please avoid modifying require.paths](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.3/api/all.html#_Note_Please_Avoid_Modifying_require.paths_)

Comment: Thanks Martjin I agree, but the thing is that this is for a simple text mate bundle which reads STDIN and add the current `process.cwd()` to the require path, so users will be able to run node code quickly, without have to change their current require paths.

Comment: Node 0.6 states that require.paths is removed Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

From the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules):

> A module prefixed with `'/'` is an absolute path to the file. For
>   example, `require('/home/marco/foo.js')` will load the file at
>   `/home/marco/foo.js`.
>
> A module prefixed with `'./'` is relative to the file calling `require()`.
>   That is, `circle.js` must be in the same directory as `foo.js` for
>   `require('./circle')` to find it.
>
> Without a leading '/' or './' to indicate a file, the module is either
>   a "core module" or is loaded from a `node_modules` folder.
>
> If the given path does not exist, `require()` will throw an Error with
>   its `code` property set to `'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'`.

---

Here’s the original answer, which refers to `require.paths` (which is no longer supported):

From the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.3/api/all.html#loading_from_the_require.paths_Folders):

In node, `require.paths` is an array of strings that represent paths to be searched for modules **when they are not prefixed with `'/'`, `'./'`, or `'../'`.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Ah ok, now that makes sense :) so, if some of the strings above are mentioned it simply ignores the paths section. So I guess there's no way to achieve that then unfortunately, thanks Martjin

Comment: Perhaps a good solution for this would be find and replace these prefixes from `process.stdin` and append the `process.cwd()` to it :) might work

Comment: @ludicco: isn’t it possible for your users to put `utils.js` in a [node_modules/](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.3/api/all.html#loading_from_node_modules_Folders) directory somewhere up the path?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass that using `NODE_PATH`

Example:

```
NODE_PATH=`pwd` node app.js
```

Comment: you are a savior! Bc some people just manage their entire codebase like that: `require('lib/mongo/get-db');`. And I have to figure out how to run this thing!

Answer (score 3):

I created a new node module called *rekuire*.

It allows you to "require" without using relative paths.

It's a big time saver when it comes to testing/refactoring.

> https://npmjs.org/package/rekuire

Comment: I was looking at the source code for rekuire and noticed it starts searching for js files by doing ./../../../ .  Does that mean if I have a few node projects in the same root folder, that they could end up sharing code?

Comment: no, it is just to establish the base folder, i specifically prevented modules bleeding between dependencies.