# NodeJS vm.runInThisContext() and lack of __filename

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whenever I run [`vm.runInThisContext(code, filename)`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/vm.html#vm.runInThisContext), the code I ran reports [`__filename`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/globals.html#__filename) and [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/globals.html#__dirname) as `undefined`.

This also leads to the situation that any `fs.readFile` and such calls will not work with relative paths. Actually to be exact, file system functions do not work at all even if I feed them a hard-coded absolute path to an existing file.

For example, this will do nothing:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/home/test/file.txt', function(e, data) {
    if (e) {throw e;}
    console.log('here i am');
});
```

What happens is that nothing happens. If I run the code in normal NodeJS code then it outputs "here i am", but if I run that code through the `vm` module, then nothing happens. The callback is simply never called, because for some reason it can't locate the file and there does not seem to be any timeouts either.

How can I make Node to understand that the executed code is some "file" and also make the `fs` module functions to work? I tried specifying the second parameter to [`vm.runInThisContext(code, filename)`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/vm.html#vm.runInThisContext), but I see no difference. It almost looks that Node doesn't care about the second parameter.

Comment: Do you mean require.paths.unshift => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390886/nodejs-require-paths-resolve-problem

Comment: I'm not touching anything related to requires.

Comment: you mean that vm.runInThisContext(code, '/home/full/path/to/file.js') does not work??

Comment: Yes, if `code` now used `__filename` or `global.__filename`, they would equal to `undefined`. This also breaks file system functions when using relative paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how I even got my code examples to work before, because right now they do not work at all.

I found out that you can use `vm.runInNewContext(code, sandbox, filename)` and then specify `require`, `__filename` and whatever you need in the sandbox:

```
// Place here some path to test it. I'm using Cygwin...
var filename = '/cygdrive/z/www/project/src/bootstrap.js';
var code = "var fs = require('fs'); fs.readFile('./path/to/some/file.js', function(e, data) {if (e) {throw e;} console.log(data.toString());});";

var vm = require('vm');
vm.runInNewContext(code, {
    require: require,
    console: console,
    __filename: filename
}, filename);
```

Then if I run `node bootstrap.js --debug` it works fine!

Comment: dwfm doesn't work for me. I only have runInNewContext inside another function.